# Enforce Bounded Nat?

Tags: scala, shapeless

How can I enforce a `Nat` that's `<= N`?

Example:

`def lessThan5(x: NatLT5) = ???`

where

`lessThan5(Nat(4))` would compile, but `lessThan5(Nat(6))` would not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the type class [`LTEq`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/nat.scala#L153) (or [`LT`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/nat.scala#L133) if you want strictly less than).

```
import shapeless.nat._
import shapeless.ops.nat._

def lessThan5[N <: Nat](n: N)(implicit ev: LTEq[N, _5]) = ???

lessThan5(_4) // compiles
lessThan5(_5) // compiles
lessThan5(_6) // doesn't compile because LTEq[_6, _5] cannot be found
```