# Int => Option[Nat]?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Does a `Int => Option[Nat]` function exist in Shapeless?

Its type signature:

```
intToOptionNat(a: Int): Option[Nat] = ???
```

Examples:

```
intToOptionNat(5)   == Some( Nat(5) )
intToOptionNat(-42) == None
```

Comment: Not 100% on this; this function does not exist in shapeless. You can use Nat.apply to create a function which does this.

Comment: `Nat` is a pretty useless type, and if you just want to check for equality you'd be better off going in the other direction. Something like `foo[N <: Nat](a: Int): Option[N]` might be a little more useful, and off the top of my head I don't know whether that exists in Shapeless.

Comment: Well, I was planning to use this question's answer into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156628/enforce-bounded-nat. Let's say I have `case class X(n: N)` where `N` is a `Nat` between 0 and 5, exclusively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is a function which will convert an `Int` to the corresponding `Nat` subtype, which will be something of the form `_0`, `Succ[_0]`, `Succ[Succ[_0]]` etc.

Because we typically want to exploit the structure of the resulting `Nat` subtype in some subsequent type level computation this is something which need to know statically, at compile time. Consequently the type `Int` isn't sufficiently precise ... we need an `Int` singleton type instead. These are not ([yet](https://github.com/typelevel/scala#typelevel-scala-2118)) directly expressible in Scala, however shapeless provides a macro-based implicit conversion for computing a `Nat` from an `Int` literal,

```
scala> import shapeless.syntax.nat._
import shapeless.syntax.nat._

scala> def intToNat(n: Nat): n.type = n
intToNat: (n: shapeless.Nat)n.type
```

Since this is computed statically there's no need for the result type to be wrapped in `Option` ... if the argument literal doesn't have a `Nat` representation it will be a compile time error,

```
scala> intToNat(5)
res0: Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[Succ[_0]]]]] = Succ()

scala> intToNat(-42)
<console>:19: error: Expression -42 does not evaluate to a non-negative Int literal
       intToNat(-42)
                 ^
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Ultimately, I'm trying to create a JSON reader (JSON -> A) for a Nat. So, as I understand, I need to dynamically build a Nat - hence the Option[Nat] return type.

Comment: As @travisbrown observed in a comment on your question the type `Option[Nat]` isn't of any use to you. I suggest you try framing your problem differently.